# verify (bitwise) if a value matches multiple specific flags of an enum

Tags: javascript, python, enums, bitwise-operators

I would like to check if a value corresponds to a set of flags (from an enum or object alike).

Right now, I have come up with the following function in javascript (praise the snippet :3):

```js
function hasFlags(flags, value) {
    let s = flags.reduce((sum, v) => sum += v, 0);
    
    return (s & value) === s
}

FLAGS = {
    STEP_0: 1 << 0,
    STEP_1: 1 << 1,
    STEP_2: 1 << 2,
    STEP_3: 1 << 3,
    STEP_4: 1 << 4,
    STEP_5: 1 << 5,
    STEP_6: 1 << 6,
    STEP_7: 1 << 7
}

const needed = [
    FLAGS.STEP_2,
    FLAGS.STEP_3,
    FLAGS.STEP_6,
]

console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4));                  // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 8));                  // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 64));                 // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8));              // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 64));             // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 8 + 64));             // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64));         // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 1));     // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 2));     // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 1 + 2)); // true
// etc...
```

In python the function would look like this:

```
def hasFlags(flags, value):
    s = sum(flags)
    return (s & value) == s

print hasFlags((4,8,64), 4)  # False
print hasFlags((4,8,64), 4+8+64)  # True
# ...
```

Is there a better way (that is, more idiomatic ... or more pythonic) to do this same verification?

Edit: Solutions in both python and javascript are appreciated, but I am  especially looking for an algorithm (whatever the language), as I've searched a lot across the web and never found any, while it seems to me that it's a common problem.

Comment: What do you mean by more pythonic ? this seems ok to me. Maybe i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which exit if a condition is wrong.

```js
const
    hasFlags = (flags, value) => flags.every(flag => flag & value),
    FLAGS = {
        STEP_0: 1 << 0,
        STEP_1: 1 << 1,
        STEP_2: 1 << 2,
        STEP_3: 1 << 3,
        STEP_4: 1 << 4,
        STEP_5: 1 << 5,
        STEP_6: 1 << 6,
        STEP_7: 1 << 7
    },
    needed = [
        FLAGS.STEP_2,
        FLAGS.STEP_3,
        FLAGS.STEP_6,
    ];

console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4));                  // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 8));                  // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 64));                 // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8));              // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 64));             // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 8 + 64));             // false
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64));         // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 1));     // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 2));     // true
console.log(hasFlags(needed, 4 + 8 + 64 + 1 + 2)); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think the question is asking about Python, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

One option in Python is a `set` of flags, where flags are elements of (for example) an enumeration from the [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module. This also has the benefit of the subset operator already being defined, so you can just do `needed <= flags`.

Your final code would look something like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Flags(enum.Enum):
  flag0 = {0}
  flag1 = {1}
  flag2 = {2}
  ...

def has_flags(needed, flags):
  return needed <= flags

needed = Flags.flag2 | 
         Flags.flag3 |
         Flags.flag6

print(has_flags(needed, Flags.flag2)) #false
print(has_flags(needed, Flags.flag3)) #false
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When combinations of flags are represented as bit-masks you can do mutations and tests on all the flags at once, directly, using bit-wise operators.

```
STEP_0 = 1 << 0
STEP_1 = 1 << 1
STEP_2 = 1 << 2
STEP_3 = 1 << 3
STEP_4 = 1 << 4
STEP_5 = 1 << 5
STEP_6 = 1 << 6
STEP_7 = 1 << 7

def has_flags(flags_to_check_for, cur_flags):
    return (cur_flags & flags_to_check_for) == flags_to_check_for

desired_flags = STEP_2 | STEP_3 | STEP_6 

cur_flags = STEP_2
print has_flags(desired_flags, cur_flags)   # False
cur_flags |= STEP_3
cur_flags |= STEP_6
print has_flags(desired_flags, cur_flags)  # True
# ...
```